# lambda:GetAlias warning in CloudFormation stack update triggered by CodeStar

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-code-deploy, aws-codestar

I am exploring CodeStar using a basic project created with the Python 3.7 Lambda template following the Serverless Project Tutorial in the AWS CodeStar documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codestar/latest/userguide/sam-tutorial.html

My build and deploy are successful. However a see a warning in my CloudFormation event log:

> The IAM user doesn't allow CloudFormation to call lambda:GetAlias, this could result in formulating a appspec file with stale CurrentVersion for CodeDeploy deployment. Please fix it to avoid any possible CodeDeploy deployment failures.

I am just using the AWS resources created automatically by the CodeStar console.

What do I do to fix this warning?

**Details**

The CodeDeploy step in the CodePipeline deploys the lambda function by updating a CloudFormation stack named: `awscodestar-<codestar project name>-lambda`.

When I looked in the event log for this stack, I noticed the above warning for the resource named `HelloWorldAliaslive`

Answer (score 2):

To fix this, add the `lambda:GetAlias` permission to the inline policy associated with the IAM role named `CodeStarWorker-<project>-CloudFormation`

1. Open the AWS Console for CodeStar
2. Click **Project** in the left navbar
3. Find the **Project Resources** section. One of the AWS IAM resources will have a name  `CodeStarWorker-<project>-CloudFormation`. Click the link in the *ARN* column of the table to open the role in IAM.
4. Locate the inline policy named *CodeStarWorkerCloudFormationRolePolicy* and click the *Edit* button.
5. Add the `"lambda:GetAlias"` action to this policy.

This policy is created automatically by CodeStar. In my account, the policy included several `Statement`s. I chose to add the `"lambda:GetAlias"` action to the statement which already had `"lambda:CreateAlias"` action.

After making this change, the warning no longer appeared in my CloudFormation event logs.